# CPLEX finds optimal LP solution but returns no basis error

Tags: python, cplex

I am solving a series of LP problems using the CPLEX Python API.
Since many of the problems are essentially the same, save a hand full of parameters. I want to use a warm start with the solution of the previous problem for most of them, by calling the function `cpx.start.set_start(col_status, row_status, col_primal, row_primal, col_dual, row_dual)` where `cpx = cplex.Cplex()`.

This function is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InitialInterface-class.html). Two of the arguments, `col_status` and `row_status`, are obtained by calling `cpx.solution.basis.get_col_basis()` and `cpx.solution.basis.get_row_basis()`.

However, despite `cpx.solution.status[cpx.solution.get_status()]` returning `optimal` and being able to obtain both `cpx.solution.get_values()` and `cpx.solution.get_dual_values()` ...

Calling `cpx.solution.basis.get_basis()` returns `CPLEX Error  1262: No basis exists.`

Now, according to [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014643478#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014676127) one can call the warm start function with empty lists for the column and row basis statuses, as follows.

```
lastsolution = cpx.solution.get_values()
cpx.start.set_start(col_status=[], row_status=[], 
                    col_primal=lastsolution, row_primal=[],
                    col_dual=[], row_dual=[])
```

However, this actually results in making a few more CPLEX iterations. Why more is unclear, but the overall goal is to have significantly less, obviously.

Version Info
Python 2.7.12
CPLEX 12.6.3

Comment: Any chance you can share your model (ideally in SAV format) on a file sharing site like http://filedropper.com?  That is, the model where after calling `cpx.solve()`, you get the "CPLEX Error  1262" when calling `cpx.solution.basis.get_basis()`.  Also, can you reproduce that behavior in the interactive?

Comment: Sharing the model is not an option at this time. Additionally, the models are extremely large. Further, I have no intention of writing and debugging several hundred lines of duplicate code for the interactive just to reproduce an error. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the [CPXERR_NO_BASIS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/macros/CPXERR_NO_BASIS.html).  See my comment.

You may have better luck if you provide the values for `row_primal`, `col_dual`, and `row_dual` too.  For example:

```
cpx2.start.set_start(col_status=[],
                     row_status=[],
                     col_primal=cpx.solution.get_values(),
                     row_primal=cpx.solution.get_linear_slacks(),
                     col_dual=cpx.solution.get_reduced_costs(),
                     row_dual=cpx.solution.get_dual_values())
```

I was able to reproduce the behavior you describe using the `afiro.mps` model that comes with the CPLEX examples (number of deterministic ticks actually increased when specifying `col_primal` alone).  However, when doing the above, it did help (number of det ticks improved and iterations went to 0).

Finally, I don't believe that there is any guarantee that using `set_start` will always help (it may even be a bad idea in some cases).  I don't have a reference for this.

Comment: I implemented the above suggestion, however, it still did not reduce the number of iterations. I even attempted to resolve the exact same problem (without changing any parameters), and the solver still went through a full set of iterations.